# Run SSH on Jenkins from file in Git

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh

I have a file on Git with the following shell script

**File Name = Job.sh**

```
echo "Warehouse script starting"
ssh -n username@server_name "mkdir -p ~/directory_name/folder_name/file_name"
```

Under `Execute Shell` in Jenkins I am running -

```
sh job.sh
```

The echo command gets printed in the console. But the job is not doing ssh into `username@server_name` and creating the directory. Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same command when connected directly to the Jenkins agent (using the account used by Jenkins on that agent)

The goal is to check if that user (on that server agent) does have the right pubic/private key pair in its `$HOME/.ssh` folder.
And double-check the public key is in `servername:~username/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Make sure the [private key is not encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727), to avoid having to deal with `ssh-agent` and passphrase caching. At least for now, for testing your setup.

Note: the `-n` option (preventing to read from stdin) is usually for ssh commands executed in the background. You might not need it in your case.

Try also to add `#!/bin/bash -x` at the beginning of your script (assuming you do have a `bash`) in order to print all lines executed.